# Is there a way to create a view having a nested array of referenced objects in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Consider these models:

users

```
{
    _id: 1,
    name: 'Some User 1'
},
{
    _id: 2,
    name: 'Some User 2'
}
```

teams

```
{
    _id: 1,
    users: [
        {
             user: 1, // (ref)
             type: "ADMIN"
        },
        {
             user: 2, // (ref)
             type: "MEMBER"
        },
    ]
}
```

vendors

```
{
    _id: 1,
    team: 1 // (ref)
}
```

groups

```
{
    _id: 1,
    vendor: 1 // (ref)
}
```

I'm trying to create a `view` that show all of the above documents without references into one single view. Here is an example:

```
{
    _id: 1,
    vendor: {
        _id: 1,
        team: {
            _id: 1,
            users: [
                {
                     user: {
                         _id: 1,
                         name: 'Some User 1'
                     },
                     type: "ADMIN"
                },
                {
                     user: {
                         _id: 2,
                         name: 'Some User 2'
                     },
                     type: "MEMBER"
                },
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my attempt creating the `view` starting from `group` collection:

```
[{
    $lookup: {
        from: 'vendors',
        localField: 'vendor',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: 'vendor'
    }
}, 
{
    $unwind: '$vendor',
    preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
}, 
{
    $lookup: {
        from: 'teams',
        localField: 'vendor.team',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: 'vendor.team'
    }
}, 
{
    $unwind: '$vendor.team',
    preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
}, 
{
    $lookup: {
        from: 'users',
        localField: 'vendor.team.users.user',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: 'vendor.team.users'
    }
}, 
{
    $unwind: '$vendor.team.users.user',
    preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
}]
```

But I'm getting:

```
{
    _id: 1,
    vendor: {
        _id: 1,
        team: {
            _id: 1,
            users: [
                {
                    _id: 1,
                    name: 'Some User 1'
                },
                {
                    _id: 2,
                    name: 'Some User 2'
                },
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I'm losing `type` at the `users` array. I've tried other ways, like `unwind`ing the `users` array but got no luck on grouping it back into one document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the solution: [Demo@mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7cY8zQhSxp-)

`aggregation pipeline` https://mongoplayground.net/p/7cY8zQhSxp-

```
db.groups.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "vendors",
      localField: "vendor",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "vendor"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$vendor",
    
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "teams",
      localField: "vendor.team",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "vendor.team"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$vendor.team",
    
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "users",
      localField: "vendor.team.users.user",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "userlist"
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "vendor.team.users": {
        $map: {
          input: "$vendor.team.users",
          as: "user",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$user",
              {
                user: {
                  $first: {
                    $filter: {
                      input: "$userlist",
                      cond: {
                        $eq: [
                          "$$user.user",
                          "$$this._id"
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unset": "userlist"
  }
])
```

`Output :`

```
//output
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "vendor": {
      "_id": 1,
      "team": {
        "_id": 1,
        "users": [
          {
            "type": "ADMIN",
            "user": {
              "_id": 1,
              "name": "Some User 1"
            }
          },
          {
            "type": "MEMBER",
            "user": {
              "_id": 2,
              "name": "Some User 2"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
]
```